# MST related edges in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose we have an undirected weighted(on edges) graph G(V,E).I need to separate  each e ∈ G(V,E) int he following types:

type1:egdge e is contained in every MST.

type2:edge e is contained in at least one MST but not all.

type3:edge e belongs in no MST.

To do this i thought about using Kruskal's algorithm with a slight modification.
If find() function detects no cycle i name the edge being processed as type 1.If find() finds a cycle i run a second find() to see if in this cycle there are edges having the same value with the one being processed.If i find at least one i name it type 2 alongside the edge being processed.Finally,E-type1-type2 are the edges that belong in no MST.This has to be written in C++.
This is kruskal's algorithm in C++ using maps:

```
// C++ program for Kruskal's algorithm to find Minimum 
// Spanning Tree of a given connected, undirected and 
// weighted graph 
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Creating shortcut for an integer pair 
typedef  pair<int, int> iPair; 

// Structure to represent a graph 
struct Graph 
{ 
    int V, E; 
    vector< pair<int, iPair> > edges; 

    // Constructor 
    Graph(int V, int E) 
    { 
        this->V = V; 
        this->E = E; 
    } 

    // Utility function to add an edge 
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int w) 
    { 
        edges.push_back({w, {u, v}}); 
    } 

    // Function to find MST using Kruskal's 
    // MST algorithm 
    int kruskalMST(); 
}; 

// To represent Disjoint Sets 
struct DisjointSets 
{ 
    int *parent, *rnk; 
    int n; 

    // Constructor. 
    DisjointSets(int n) 
    { 
        // Allocate memory 
        this->n = n; 
        parent = new int[n+1]; 
        rnk = new int[n+1]; 

        // Initially, all vertices are in 
        // different sets and have rank 0. 
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
        { 
            rnk[i] = 0; 

            //every element is parent of itself 
            parent[i] = i; 
        } 
    } 

    // Find the parent of a node 'u' 
    // Path Compression 
    int find(int u) 
    { 
        /* Make the parent of the nodes in the path 
           from u--> parent[u] point to parent[u] */
        if (u != parent[u]) 
            parent[u] = find(parent[u]); 
        return parent[u]; 
    } 

    // Union by rank 
    void merge(int x, int y) 
    { 
        x = find(x), y = find(y); 

        /* Make tree with smaller height 
           a subtree of the other tree  */
        if (rnk[x] > rnk[y]) 
            parent[y] = x; 
        else // If rnk[x] <= rnk[y] 
            parent[x] = y; 

        if (rnk[x] == rnk[y]) 
            rnk[y]++; 
    } 
}; 

 /* Functions returns weight of the MST*/ 

int Graph::kruskalMST() 
{ 
    int mst_wt = 0; // Initialize result 

    // Sort edges in increasing order on basis of cost 
    sort(edges.begin(), edges.end()); 

    // Create disjoint sets 
    DisjointSets ds(V); 

    // Iterate through all sorted edges 
    vector< pair<int, iPair> >::iterator it; 
    for (it=edges.begin(); it!=edges.end(); it++) 
    { 
        int u = it->second.first; 
        int v = it->second.second; 

        int set_u = ds.find(u); 
        int set_v = ds.find(v); 

        // Check if the selected edge is creating 
        // a cycle or not (Cycle is created if u 
        // and v belong to same set) 
        if (set_u != set_v) 
        { 
            // Current edge will be in the MST 
            // so print it 
            cout << u << " - " << v << endl; 

            // Update MST weight 
            mst_wt += it->first; 

            // Merge two sets 
            ds.merge(set_u, set_v); 
        } 
    } 

    return mst_wt; 
} 

// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    /* Let us create above shown weighted 
       and unidrected graph */
    int V = 9, E = 14; 
    Graph g(V, E); 

    //  making above shown graph 
    g.addEdge(0, 1, 4); 
    g.addEdge(0, 7, 8); 
    g.addEdge(1, 2, 8); 
    g.addEdge(1, 7, 11); 
    g.addEdge(2, 3, 7); 
    g.addEdge(2, 8, 2); 
    g.addEdge(2, 5, 4); 
    g.addEdge(3, 4, 9); 
    g.addEdge(3, 5, 14); 
    g.addEdge(4, 5, 10); 
    g.addEdge(5, 6, 2); 
    g.addEdge(6, 7, 1); 
    g.addEdge(6, 8, 6); 
    g.addEdge(7, 8, 7); 

    cout << "Edges of MST are \n"; 
    int mst_wt = g.kruskalMST(); 

    cout << "\nWeight of MST is " << mst_wt; 

    return 0; 
}
```

I am having trouble implementing the second find in which given the source and destination of an edge i need somehow to know it's weight.How could this be done?

Comment: I think the main problem here is not the weights, you could easily store the `<edge, weight>` pairs in the hashmap. The main problem is finding the edges of a cycle. Obviously all nodes forming a cycle are located in the set that the nodes of currently processed edge (the one that forms a cycle) belong to.

Comment: I was going to suggest recursively inspecting all edges going up to the set root (in `find()`) for both nodes of processed edge, but then I realized that such inspection does not necessarily give cycle edges only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at Kruskal Algorithm which solves MST in O(m log m) time. Sort the edges first in weight non-decreasing order, then process each edge. if the edge connects two different connected components, add this edge to MST then combine two components. We use disjoint-set union here to maintain connectivity.

The main point is that only those edges with same weight may replace each other in MST. First of all, sort edges as what Kruskal do. To get the answer, we construct MST in weight non-decreasing order and process all edges with same weight together. Now on each step, we are to face some edges with same weight x and a forest of connected components.

Note that for an edge, what points it connects does not matter, we only need to know what components it connects. Now build a new graph G', each point in G' is a connected component in the original forest, and edges are added to connect components that it connected before. Time complexity is O(|E|) here, with careful implementation.

Let's answer queries on these edges. First of all, if an edge in G' is a loop(connects the same component), this edge must not appear in any MSTs. If after deleting an edge V in G', G's connectivity is changed (A connected component in G' spilt into two. We call these edges bridge), V must be in any of MST. All edges left can appear in some MSTs, but not any.

What's left is to get all of V quickly. Maybe you hear about Tarjan before, he invented an algorithm based on DFS to get all bridges in an edge-undirected graph in O(|V|+|E|). Read this page on Wikipedia for detailed information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)

Considering those components which don't have any edges connected don't need to be appear in G', we have |V|<=2|E|, so time complexity for Tarjan's DFS is O(|E|), where |E| is count of edges weighted x. Because each edge will be used exactly once in G', total time complexity except sorting is O(m).

My solution to this problem:
https://codeforces.com/contest/160/submission/5734719

Sources:

https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4108

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/160/D